# Who was watching Mary in her childhood?

Tags: shikkoku-no-sharnoth

After the credits there is a final flashback of Mary and Charlotte when they were children , they talk about the Shadow Builder and how he hates humans because "when God said 'Let there be light' he went away", Charlotte worries about the existence of the Shadow Builder for Mary's safety, yet Mary reaffirms that she'll be ok and will protect Charlotte saying that since that the Shadow Builder can understand her because he listen to god.

At the end of the scene, Charlotte notices in Mary's shadow a red eye, the same kind of eye which is depicted though the entire story being associated with Sharnoth, this eye however is just watching and it has no red tear.

I am wondering who this eye represented and what reason did they have as she did not have her Golden Eye at this time.

Answer (score 1):

The eye was James. Hence the part where it says the "red eye warped/as if looking at something bright" hearkening back to the many times it mentions James doing the same.

Comment: Is James M? i remember when Mary and M first meet Bram Stoker M introduces himself as James Moriarty but we know that's not true as James Moriarty is shown at the end when Sherlock confronts him

Comment: James is "M," and the real Moriarty gave him his body years ago. Hence the real Moriarty only existing in that little pocket dimension and inexplicably knowing things about the plot. Those parts were added in the Full-Voice Reborn version of the game to add a bit of exposition that some people needed to understand the plot. He's not really James Moriarty, but that's the name he's assumed for his human form. It's likely that he is supposed to be Nyarlathotep, or something similar to Nyarlathotep.

Comment: hmmm, interesting, i always wondering why there was a Cathulu Mythos tag on VNDB when the only mention of Lovecraft was in the Web Novel. it being a pocket dimension would explain why Charlotte and Mary both spoke to Moriarty as if in present time given Charlotte's condition

Comment: If you are interested, would you like to have a look at [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47968/which-entity-of-the-cthulhu-mythos-does-mary-meet)